# Trying To Assign SQL*Plus Output To Tupple (Two-Dimensional Array) In Python 2.7

Tags: python, oracle, sqlplus

At work, we're unable to use the cx_oracle module due to the security environment. We're stuck using SQLPLUS. Finding online code, I was able to successfully run SQL queries but the issue is that the result of the query is not easy to work with. I was wondering if someone could assist with fixing the output so that it will just throw the query results into a tupple with two dimensions representing columns and rows. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
 
#function that takes the sqlCommand and connectString and returns the queryReslut and errorMessage (if any)
def runSqlQuery(sqlCommand, connectString):
   session = Popen(['sqlplus', '-S', connectString], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
   session.stdin.write(sqlCommand)
   return session.communicate()
```

The function is invoked like this:

```
sqlCommand='select * from <database-name-removed> where payrollnumber in (1111);'
connectString=username + '/' + password + '@SERVER'
queryResult, errorMessage = runSqlQuery(sqlCommand, connectString)
```

When I perform a "print queryresult", I'll receive output in a kind of wonky format like so:

```
  PERSONID PAYROLLNUMBER EMPLOYEEPREFIX LASTNAME
---------- ------------- -------------- ------------------------------
FIRSTNAME                 MI       ACTIVE      UN_ID
------------------------- ---- ---------- ----------
     11111         99999                NEWMAN
ALFRED                             1
```

This is obviously not easy to parse. I would like to preserve the column names for row 0. In this example, the tupple would look something like this:

```
tupple=["PERSONID", "PAYROLLNUMBER", "EMPLOYEEPREFIX", "LASTNAME", "FIRSTNAME", "MI", "ACTIVE", "UN_ID"]
       ["11111", "99999", "", "NEWMAN", "ALFRED", "", "1", ""]
```

In the second row of data, the MI, EMPLOYEEPREFIX, and UN_ID are blank so this is why there are missing values.

Thanks!

Comment: This is _worse_ for security, as it prevents you from using bind parameters and so increases the risk of SQL injection attacks (as well as introducing potential for vulnerabilities triggered by errors in the code that parses results). Talk to your security staff about it, they should make an exception.

Comment: (also, unless it's been substantially redesigned in the intervening decade, sqlplus is particularly badly designed for secure, unambiguous use; at a former job, I built a Python tool using cx_Oracle to replace it for precisely that reason)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not the system administrator so I don't have the ability to install software on the server. The system administrators are contracted out so we have to submit requests but these are oftentimes disapproved. If anyone actually has a solution, this would be best. I would have definitely preferred to use cx_Oracle.

Comment: It should be easy to make a request that your sysadmins will agree to approve here; the security and performance advantages are nontrivial. That said, you don't _need_ root access to install Python modules in most cases -- if there's any location on disk you _can_ write through, you can just install them there (or in a virtualenv located there) and add them to `sys.path`.

Comment: If you really can't use Oracle's cx_Oracle module, run SQL*Plus with a big SET LINESIZE.  Use SET NULL to print something for the nulls.  Or look at https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/fast-generation-of-csv-and-json-from-oracle-database and get CSV out that you can parse with the standard Python csv module.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the columns and put separators between them. For example here is how I get the current SCN number using sqlplus in Python:

```
    scn_query = """
COLUMN SCN FORMAT 999999999999999
CREATE TABLE tempscnnumber ( scn varchar2(25));
INSERT INTO tempscnnumber VALUES(
TO_CHAR(userenv('commitscn'),999999999999999));
commit;
select 'S'||'CN:'||to_number(SCN) from tempscnnumber;
drop table tempscnnumber;
exit;
    """
```

Later in the code I search the output of sqlplus for SCN:

```
    """
Output is like:

'S'||'CN:'||CURRENT_SCN
--------------------------------------------
SCN:77262587

    """

# Find the line with SCN
    for line in output:
        if line[0:4]=="SCN:":
            scn = line[4:]
            return int(scn)

    return -1
```

It is not pretty. If you want a bunch of columns just concatenate them with ||':'|| if your output does not have colons or use ||'%*%%^&'|| or any string not in your output.

Bobby

Comment: If the original poster can only run the query in SQL\*Plus, I'd still vote to use SQL\*Plus's SET MARKUP CSV mode instead of manual concatenation.  And, of course, if the query is run in Python cx_Oracle none of this is needed!